# Get max score and the fields in the max score row in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| id | uid  | score   | date    |
————————————————————————————————
| 1  | aaa  | 10      | 2017.7.7|

| 2  | bbb  | 5       | 2017.7.7|

| 3  | aaa  | 15      | 2017.7.7|

| 4  | bbb  | 20      | 2017.7.8|
```

I want to get everyone’s max score and every row should include all fields like id and date.

```
| id | uid | score | date    |
—————————————————————————————
| 4  | bbb | 20    | 2017.7.8|

| 3  | aaa | 15    | 2017.7.7|
```

`Select max(score) as score, id, date, uid from data group by uid order by score desc`

I can use this sql to get what I want in MySQL before v5.7 but you know after MySQL 5.7 there is a sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. So I can’t get the result as before. I see there are some answers tell me to disable the mode. But I want to know if there are any sql can do this as well as I don’t disable the mode.

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem,kindly mark it as an answer and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to rewrite the same query by using left join without use of aggregate function

```
select a.*
from data a
left join data b on a.uid = b.uid
and a.score < b.score
where b.uid is null
```

Note it may return multiple rows for single uid if there are rows with same highest score you might need a CASE statement and another attribute to decide which row should be picked to handle this kind of situation

[Demo using MySQL 5.7.12](http://rextester.com/GYGOPN83065)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to change this property for only this query by using

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the mode with following query:

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Also, your query will only  show max `score` of `uid` but not it's relevant `id` and `date`.

```
Select max(score) as score, id, date, uid 
from data 
where (uid,score) in (select uid,max(score) 
                      from data
                      group by uid
                     )
group by uid 
order by score desc
```

Comment: Is it working as expected?